# Can no longer push or pull Amplify

Tags: aws-amplify

I can't `amplify pull` or `amplify push` anymore and get an error:

```
EEXIST: file already exists, symlink '../../../../../../../../../../../../../opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3.8' -> '...projectdir/amplify/.temp/#current-cloud-backend/function/funcname/.venv/bin/python'
```

If I delete the offending file, push and pull fail with a warning that the file is *missing*. This continues to happen even if I completely delete the function from my project locally or if I delete it from the backend using the console.

(I've also rebuilt the function locally with a copy of python rather than a symlink — necessary for `amplify mock` to work — but get the circular errors in that case as well.)

It seems like the symlink got pushed earlier and now blocks any further push or pull. Is there a way to just push (with out pulling) what I have locally to the backend?

Answer (score 1):

The Amplify CLI cannot handle symlinks in Lambda functions because of the zip and unzip operations performed by push/pull operations on the `#current-cloud-backend` folder.

One approach to fixing this is to manually download the `#current-cloud-backend.zip` from the deployment bucket on S3, unzip it, remove any symlinks, rezip it, and then upload back to S3. In other words yet another dive out of Amplify into the guts of AWS. Hardly a solution.

A more Amplify-ish approach is to first save any hard to restore customizations to the offending component. And then:

Make a fresh local instance and delete offending component there:

```
mkdir TMP
cd TMP
amplify pull
amplify remove ...
amplify push -y —force
cd ..
rm -rf TMP
```

Then in the project folder:

```
amplify pull
amplify add ...
# edit to restore to previous state
amplify push
```

Of course the best thing is to avoid symlinks in the first place, which in many cases will be from Python venvs in the a function's folder (required for `mock` to work) that link to the Python executable. The way to avoid that is to:

```
export PIPENV_VIRTUALENV_COPIES=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `amplify push -y --force` to forcibly push your local changes to the backend. If you (or someone else) made backend changes that didn't get 'pulled', they will/may be lost by forcing the push.

Comment: That was the first thing I tired. No luck. Whatever I do it either pulls a symlink from the backend or complains that the file is missing.

Comment: Odd. The Amplify discord channel is pretty active. You may find better help there.

Comment: Yeah asking over there too.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with temp files from Amplify backend.
Try deleting the /myProject/amplify/.temp/ directory and running amplify push again.

Comment: It turns out to be a fatal issue with Amplify. Push (which should certainly not be called that) can irretrievably corrupt the backend files on the server under certain circumstances, rendering the whole app unsalvageable. One of many many reasons to avoid Amplify and seek another solution.